# Is there any problem with my code here? I am having trouble with the result

Tags: python

Here is my code: I'd like to decode the string from "3[b2[ca]]" to "bcacabcacabcaca". But my result is "[[[". Can someone help me with that?

```
def decompression(text):
    intStack = []
    charStack = []
    temp = ""
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].isdigit():
            times = 0
            while text[i].isdigit():
                times = times * 10 + int(text[i])
                i += 1
            i -= 1
            intStack.append(times)
        elif text[i] == ']':
            temp = ""
            times = 0
            if len(intStack) > 0:
                times = intStack[-1]
                intStack.pop()
            while len(charStack) > 0 and charStack[-1] != '[':
                temp += charStack[-1]
                charStack.pop()
            if len(charStack) > 0 and charStack[-1] == '[':
                charStack.pop()
            for j in range(times):
                result += temp
            for j in range(len(result)):
                charStack.append(result[j])
            result = ""
        elif text[i] == '[':
            if text[i-1].isdigit():
                charStack.append(text[i])
            else:
                charStack.append(text[i])
                intStack.append(1)
        else:
            charStack.append(text[1])
    while len(charStack) != 0:
        result += charStack[-1]
        charStack.pop()
    return result

print(decompression("3[b2[ca]]"))
```

I am having the wrong answer all the time, I've checked it several times and tested with other online editors but what's wrong with this code? I cannot figure it out still.

Comment: Please provide sample input and the expected output and with the output from the existing code.

Comment: What is the input to your function? what is the expected result? by the way, is your indentation correct?

Comment: "3[b2[ca]" is my input and my output is "[[[". must be bcacabcacabcaca

Comment: Is the `1` in `charStack.append(text[1])` a typo?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small typo in the last else statement. It says

```
else: 
    charStack.append(text[1])
```

this should be

```
else: 
    charStack.append(text[i])
```

Also you should indent everything in the function, otherwise python won't know it's part of the function.

```
def decompression(text):
    intStack = []
    charStack = []
    temp = ""
    result = ""

    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].isdigit():
            times = 0
            while text[i].isdigit():
                times = times * 10 + int(text[i])
                i += 1
            i -= 1
            intStack.append(times)
        elif text[i] == ']':
            temp = ""
            times = 0
            if len(intStack) > 0:
                times = intStack[-1]
                intStack.pop()
            while len(charStack) > 0 and charStack[-1] != '[':
                temp += charStack[-1]
                charStack.pop()
            if len(charStack) > 0 and charStack[-1] == '[':
                charStack.pop()
            for j in range(times):
                result += temp
            for j in range(len(result)):
                charStack.append(result[j])
            result = ""
        elif text[i] == '[':
            if text[i-1].isdigit():
                charStack.append(text[i])
            else:
                charStack.append(text[i])
                intStack.append(1)
        else:
            charStack.append(text[i])
    while len(charStack) != 0:
        result += charStack[-1]
        charStack.pop()
    return result
```

Comment: Ohhh, I didn not pay attention that, thank you. Damnit, it work now)))). Excuse me for my careless

Answer (score 0):

Other than the above mentioned answers and comments your logic for finding intStack doesn't work if the integers aren't single digits, I mean in your sample input 3[b2[ca]] the intStack would be [3,2] that's fine but if the input is 33[b22[c6[a]]] the intStack should be [33,22,6] but your logic fails in this case.

Try this for finding intStack:

```
intStack = [];
index=[];
for i in range(len(text)):
    if i not in index:
        if text[i].isdigit():
            times="";
            while text[i].isdigit():
                times+=text[i]
                index.append(i);
                i+=1
            intStack.append(int(times))
```

Comment: while text[i].isdigit():
                times = times * 10 + int(text[i])
                i += 1
            i -= 1
            intStack.append(times)
this while loop is used to take multi digits from the list, i think it takes more than 2 digit numbers.

Comment: Yes you can use that while loop too but make sure you are appending only the integers which aren't already appended, In your original code if you give '33[b22[ca]' as input, the intStack is populated as '[33, 3, 22, 2]' instead of '[33,22]' in order to avoid this I added an if condition to check if we've been through that index or not.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not the best practice, it works:

```py
text = "3[b2[ca]]"
list = list(text)
try:
    for i in range(len(list)*2):
        if list[i] == '[':
            list[i] = '*('
        if list[i] == ']':
            list[i] = ')'
        if list[i].isalpha() and list[i+1].isdigit():
            list.insert(i+1,"+")
        if list[i].isalpha() and list[i+1].isalpha():
            list.insert(i+1,"+")
        if list[i].isalpha():
            globals()[list[i]] = str(list[i])
except:
    pass

print(list)
result = ''.join(list)
print(result)
print(eval(result))
```

Basically, what it does is:

- takes the text and transforms it into a list;
- iterates over the double the length of the list (we make some appends to the list during the loop itself, hence the double value);
- the whole iteration is inside a `try: except: pass` so that we ignore the `IndexError: list index out of range` error;
- during the iteration, we make some find and replace, slowly transforming the string into a math expression: `[...]` is replaced with `*(...)`, where it finds a letter followed by a number, it adds `+` sign, and also where it finds letters next to each other;
- finally, using `globals()` builtin function (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) we take each letter from the list and declare it as a variable that takes the string representation of itself as a value;
- all we have to do now is to join the elements of the list and using `eval()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval on that result string, we have the result:

```py
>>> print(text)
3[b2[ca]]
>>> print(list)
['3', '*(', 'b', '+', '2', '*(', 'c', '+', 'a', ')', ')']
>>> result = ''.join(list)
>>> print(result)
3*(b+2*(c+a))
>>> print(eval(result))
bcacabcacabcaca
```